# keys in a std::set get changed on insert

Tags: c++, linux, stl

I currently have a very weird issue where the following code misbehaves:

```
std::set<int> simpleSet;
for( int i=0; i<10; ++i )
    simpleSet.insert( i );
```

Yes, it's really just inserting (or emplacing, same result) something into a set. Anyway, up to i=6 everything is fine but upon inserting 7 the set goes from

```
Locals
    i   7   int
    simpleSet   <7 items>   std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> >
        [0] 0   int
        [1] 1   int
        [2] 2   int
        [3] 3   int
        [4] 4   int
        [5] 5   int
        [6] 6   int
```

to

```
Locals
    i   8   int
    simpleSet   <8 items>   std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> >
        [0] 0   int
        [1] 1   int
        [2] 2   int
        [3] 1   int
        [4] 2   int
        [5] 1   int
        [6] 2   int
        [7] 1   int
```

in the debugger. This is reproducable with other datatypes and random values. Always on inserting the 8th element all previous elements are changed. Inserting more just adds more 1s and 2s to the set for some reason, and in new buckets.

I'm working on Linux with glibc version 2.26 and gcc 7.2.0 or clang 4.0.1 (both produce the same problem).

**Edit:** This is issue with the debug data visualizer in QtCreator (and maybe other IDEs). When writing the contents of the set to stdout it prints the correct values.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the set. The data visualizer just has problems keeping up with the rebalancing of the BST.

Comment: everything fine with your code. Post more about the exact workflow you use, for me it works fine with clang.

Comment: @StoryTeller you seem to be right. When I cout the set it gives the correct result. Sorry for not trying that earlier. That is really strange because the data visualizer has no problems with maps or other containers, just with set and multiset.

Comment: @JayTea - Not *that* odd. Those visualizers are mini-pieces of software, and can have bugs too. You didn't specify what debugger you used, but you can possibly file a bug report.

Comment: @StoryTeller of course, you're right. Thanks for your help. I'm using gdb and QtCreator btw. Filing a bug report now.